# integral of exp of rational function

Tags: integration, exponential-function, rational-functions

I reopen the question with more context. I was unaware of the Stack Overflow directives. Please apologize.

Background: The sun is a star. Billions of stars (e.g. say $10^{12}$) make a galaxy. This integral might come out in the computation of how much light gets each star from the others (i.e., in the processes of the interstellar medium) that I'm playing with.

It doesn't require much more details to understand that having a closed form for this integral can be important for me, being it computed millions of times: even if I reduce the number of its computations, analytic will be always faster than numeric in the long runs.

$$\int_0^T {\frac{{{Exp[{ - \frac{a}{t} + bt]}}}}{{{t^{3/2}}}}dt}$$

I've tried with a change of variables in the exp... but not a good idea so far :/

Finally, it's astrophysics: a>0, b>0, T>0. All reals, all "easy" ;)

ThX in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: did u try to put your integral into https://www.integral-calculator.com/ it's an integral calculator.

Comment: Yes, please apologize for my sloppy writing: a>0, b>0, and T>0 reals. And Yes, I've tried without success integral-calculator.com. Anybody has a license of Mathematica or Maple to have a try, please?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is the steps to your integral you can use the website https://www.integral-calculator.com/ for further integral help

Comment: This is not the problem. $bt$ is part of the exponential.

Comment: Yes... thanks for your help, but indeed as @ClaudeLeibovici stressed, this is not the problem. :/